# Download or revert a locally modified file

Tags: git, github

I've modified a file and want to get the file without modifications from the server I `git pull`ed it from. How can I download the file from the server, or get back the file's initial state?

Comment: Is the modification just staged, or has it already been committed?

Comment: the modification is just staged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is just staged, you do this to unstage the file:

```
git reset HEAD filename
```

Then to discard the modifications you've made to it:

```
git checkout -- filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for git stash command

Comment: With git stash, if I modificate only one file, I can git stast. ;) But after git pull, if I modificate two files and I want to back the initial state only one file, not work.

Comment: If it is one exact file you need to revert, why dont you just go to your git history and revert back... Another thing you can do is use some tools like gitx. They are quite nice to discard specific changes.